# Open a link in a frame/lightbox

Tags: iframe, popup

im using wordpress and want to add a link which open in a frame/lightbox. Cant find a small solution for that.

There should be no new window. Just a content box which appear inside the page where i am. I hope u know what i mean

Answer (score 1):

That should be pretty easy using the [Easy Fancybox](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/#can%20i%20display%20web%20pages%20or%20html%20files%20in%20a%20fancybox%20overlay%3F) plugin.

Citing the entry from the FAQ section of the plugin's page:

> **Can I display web pages or HTML files in a FancyBox overlay?**
>
> Yes. First, enable the *iFrame* option on *Settings* > *Media*. Then, in your post or page content create a link to any web page or .htm(l) file in your content. Then switch to the *Text* tab in the Classic Editor or to *Edit as HTML* (under *More* options in the block menu) in Gutenberg, find the link `<a ... >` tag and give it a `class="fancybox-iframe"` attribute.

Voilà !

Beware, though, that:

> Note: Not all external web pages are allowed to be embedded in an iframe and may be blocked by a server response header or script. The result will be either an empty/blank light box or the target page “breaking out” of the light box and loading in the main browser tab.

And you'd probably face the same problem with any other iframe solution. So that would work better with locally served pages.